# Eclipse cannot detect blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Eclipse plugin : BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.5.2_indigo

Device : Blackberry curve 9315 / 9320 , Software version - 7.1 Bundle 1319.
I have also installed the simulator for 9320

The packaging , signing processes do not show any error.

When I do "Load project(s) on device " or Debug , the plugin says - No device detected.

The device is detected by the Desktop software.

I have read a few solutions on SO but none seem to solve the issue.
On this [link](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html) , the "select your smartphone" and "Select your OS" drop downs are empty, where can I get the generic simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the simulator download [link](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html) again?  It seems to be working for me.